# Android List with a bigger item in the middle

Tags: android

For my App I need some sort of list that shows steps of a task. I want it to show three items at the same time with the current one in a bigger font. The user should also be able to either scroll per gestures or with button.

It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: I think this library is helpful for you to want https://github.com/alirezat775/carousel-view/

Comment: @AlirezaTizfahmFard i don't want to relay on third party libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you

Adapter

```
public class CenterZoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CenterZoomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final String TAG = CenterZoomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private final int NUMBERS_OF_ITEM_TO_DISPLAY = 3;
    private Context context;
    private int snapPosition = 1;

    public CenterZoomAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_center_zoom, parent, false);

        itemView.getLayoutParams().height
                = (int) (getScreenHeight() / NUMBERS_OF_ITEM_TO_DISPLAY); /// THIS LINE WILL DIVIDE OUR VIEW INTO NUMBERS OF PARTS

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setSnapView();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    public void setSnapPosition(int snapPosition) {
        this.snapPosition = snapPosition;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getScreenHeight() {

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        return size.y;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        }

        public void setSnapView() {
            if (getAdapterPosition() == snapPosition) {
                tv.setTextSize(28);
            } else {
                tv.setTextSize(20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="item position"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Initialize recyclerview

```
rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(rv.getContext(),
                RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        rv.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        adapter = new CenterZoomAdapter(this);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);

        rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    View centerView = helper.findSnapView(layoutManager);
                    int pos = layoutManager.getPosition(centerView);
                    adapter.setSnapPosition(pos);
                    Log.e("Snapped Item Position:",""+pos);
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: I will try asap

Comment: It is working. Only thing that is not so good, is that the last item will never get in the middle. I solved it by adding a dummy item in the end. Thank you.